# Quartz.Net Remove Proxy Azure WebJob

Tags: quartz.net, azure-webjobs

Is it possible to run Quartz.Net in an Azure WebJob and communicate with it using a RemoteClient proxy? If so, how could I figure out what the address would be?

```
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="RemoteClient"/>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.proxy" value="true"/>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.proxy.address" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:555/QuartzScheduler"/>
</quartz>
```

I know that Azure has its own scheduling mechanisms, but my application has to run in both Azure and Self-Hosted environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure WebJob has the same sandbox limitation as the Azure Website in which it cannot open an arbitrary port and listen on it.

One possible way to communicate with a WebJob is via persistent queues (like Azure storage queue, servicebus queue or any other).